# Lua script for RGB control

Tags: lua, rgb

I recently downloaded [an RGB program](https://github.com/ixjf/MSIRGB) for the LEDs in my computer. The program lets you create scripts for the lighting. I'm looking to create something like [this (a colour fade cycle)](https://codepen.io/Codepixl/pen/ogWWaK) but since I haven't coded in Lua before and all I'm going from are the other example scripts. This is what I have currently:

```
`-- Variables

local delay = 10 -- this is the update rate, in milliseconds
local colour_step = 1.1

--
Lighting.SetStepDuration(200)
Lighting.SetFlashingSpeed(0)
Lighting.SetBreathingModeEnabled(false)

--local r = 15
--local g = 0
--local b = 0

local r, g, b = Lighting.ColourUtils.HSVtoRGB(0, 0.0933, 1)

while true do
    if r > 0 and b == 0 then
        r = r - 1
    g = g + 1
    end
    if g > 0 and r == 0 then
        g = g - 1
    b = b + 1
    end
    if b > 0 and g == 0 then
        b = b - 1
    r = r + 1
    end

    r = tonumber(("%x"):format(r * 15), 16)
    g = tonumber(("%x"):format(g * 15), 16)
    b = tonumber(("%x"):format(b * 15), 16)

    Lighting.BatchBegin()
    for i = 1, 8 do
        Lighting.SetColour(i, r, g, b)
    end
    Lighting.BatchEnd()
    os.sleep(delay)
end'
```

This comes up with the error:

```
bad argument #2 to 'SetColour' (value is out of range (range is 0x0-0xF))
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is quite clear: the acceptable range of values for the color is 0-15, but you pass a value that is outside of that range. It looks like you can simply remove your `r = tonumber(("%x"):format(r * 15), 16)` line(s), as it's the same as `r = r * 15`, which is probably not needed in your case.

Comment: Thanks, it now deems quite a simple error. The code was made from bits of the other example scripts provided, so that's why my code is a bit crude, with unnecessary bits.